# How do I give sliding effects to buttons (in a grid)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a candy crush game with buttons as candies. I have been able to lay the grid of candies (buttons) with each button assigned to random color class (among given 4). This is shown in the image below:

[image: candy / button grid]

Candy/button grid

How can I click and drag each button to have a sliding-swapping effect with neighbour buttons (like in swapping candies in the game) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gabriel You're making me feel guilty man. I am new to this. I am still looking on how to do it. :( 
But I have been able to make the grid as shown in the image till now (with the help of fellow stackoverflowers ) - buttons generated with random colors.

Comment: It's not about guilt but, 1. In order to give you a specific answer (e.g. add this code (..) in line 12) it will be easier to see what have you done so far. 2. People want to make sure you put some efforts on the research before they give you their time. I believe that this is what @Gabriel meant :)

Comment: You have to experiment a little and then ask specific questions here. You could use actual drag and drop https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/dnd/basics/ (note that this doesn't work on mobile), a framework like jQuery UI, or you could listen to `mousedown` and `mousemove` events to detect in which direction the cursor/finger moved.